# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) - AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, json, console.log

I am quite certain that all the arguments I passed into `register()` have values. This is the `js` code.

```
$scope.register = function(
    $reg_code, $prov_code, $citymun_code, $brgy_code, $street,
    $user_name, $user_email, $user_contact, $user_password
) {
    //displays the arguments 
    alert("region: " + $reg_code + ", province: " + $prov_code + ", citymun: " + $citymun_code   +  ", barangay: "
  + $brgy_code + ", street: " + $street + ", user_name: " + $user_name + ", user_email: " + $user_email + ", user_contact: "
  + $user_contact + ", user_password: " + $user_password);

    $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://" + host + "/mobile/register.php",
      data: JSON.stringify({
          user_password_reg: $user_password,
          user_email_reg: $user_email,
          user_contact_reg: $user_contact,
          user_name_reg: $user_name,
          region: $reg_code,
          province: $prov_code,
          citymun: $citymun_code,
          barangay: $brgy_code,
          street: $street,
          echo: "1",
          success: "0",
          user_acc_type: "log account"
      }),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function(res) {
          alert("success1: " + res.data.success1 + ", success2: " + res.data.success2 + ", success3: " + res.data.success3);
    });


}
```

This is the php script

```
<?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    //converts data to post
    $postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $post = json_decode($postData);


    $echo = array();
    $echo["success1"] = 0;
    $echo["success2"] = 0;
    $echo["success3"] = 0;

    if(isset($post["region"]) &&
        isset($post["province"]) &&
        isset($post["citymun"]) &&
        isset($post["barangay"]) &&
        isset($post["street"]) &&
        isset($post["user_password_reg"]) &&
        isset($post["user_name_reg"]) &&
        isset($post["user_email_reg"]) &&
        isset($post["user_contact_reg"])
    ) {
        $echo["success1"] = 1;
        $echo["success2"] = 1;
        $echo["success3"] = 1;

    } else {

        $echo["success1"] = 2;
        $echo["success2"] = 2;
        $echo["success3"] = 2;
    }

    echo json_encode($echo);
 ?>
```

This programs is still not complete. I first wanted to make sure that the php is getting all the right parameters from post and returns or `echo`es a right value. However, in these code I get this error in  the console.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at fromJson (ionic.bundle.js:9892)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (ionic.bundle.js:17406)
    at ionic.bundle.js:17491
    at forEach (ionic.bundle.js:9150)
    at transformData (ionic.bundle.js:17490)
    at transformResponse (ionic.bundle.js:18216)
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:22016)
    at ionic.bundle.js:22032
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:23228)
```

if `<` is read in the json output of the php, that means there was an error on the part of the php code. It's quite hard for me to debug the php code since the AngularJS automatically parses the data from the php. Hence, I cannot see the details of the error. And besides I really doubt that this simple php script would have an error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply check the response in your browser's *Network* console. Why are you POSTing JSON data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? If it's to keep the request *simple*, I'd just go with `text/plain`

Comment: not sure what's the use of `x-www-form-urlencoded` ..

Comment: You should know why you use the code that you write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP code is probably triggering an error resulting in an HTML response.

This is most likely due to the fact you're attempting to access object properties as array indices, triggering something like

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Change your code to

```
$post = json_decode($postData, true);
```

See http://php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-parameters

---

I also assume you're using `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to keep the request [*simple*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests). I would recommend `text/plain` instead as your data is certainly not URL encoded.

```
$http.post("http://" + host + "/mobile/register.php", {
  user_password_reg: $user_password,
  user_email_reg: $user_email,
  user_contact_reg: $user_contact,
  user_name_reg: $user_name,
  region: $reg_code,
  province: $prov_code,
  citymun: $citymun_code,
  barangay: $brgy_code,
  street: $street,
  echo: "1",
  success: "0",
  user_acc_type: "log account"
}, {
  headers: { 'Content-type': 'text/plain' }
})
```